# Why Segmentation fault is happening in this openmp code?

Tags: fortran, openmp

main program:

```
program main                                                                                                                                                    
  use omp_lib                                                                                                                                                   
  use my_module                                                                                                                                                 
  implicit none                                                                                                                                                 

  integer, parameter :: nmax = 202000                                                                                                                           
  real(8) :: e_in(nmax) = 0.D0                                                                                                                                  
  integer i                                                                                                                                                     

call omp_set_num_threads(2)                                                                                                                                     
!$omp parallel default(firstprivate)                                                                                                                            
!$omp do                                                                                                                                                        
  do i=1,2                                                                                                                                                      
     print *, e_in(i)                                                                                                                                           
     print *, eTDSE(i)                                                                                                                                          
  end do                                                                                                                                                        
!$omp end do                                                                                                                                                    
!$omp end parallel                                                                                                                                              
end program main
```

module:

```
module my_module                                                                                                                                                
  implicit none                                                                                                                                                 

  integer, parameter, private :: ntmax = 202000                                                                                                  
  double complex :: eTDSE(ntmax) = (0.D0,0.D0)                                                                                                                  
!$omp threadprivate(eTDSE)                                                                                                                                      

end module my_module
```

compiled using:

```
ifort -openmp main.f90 my_module.f90
```

It gives the Segmentation fault when execution. If remove one of the print commands in the main program, it runs fine. Also if remove the omp function and compile without -openmp option, it runs fine too.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The most probable cause for this behaviour is that your stack size limit is too small (for whatever reason). Since `e_in` is private to each OpenMP thread, one copy per thread is allocated on the thread stack (even if you have specified `-heap-arrays`!). `202000` elements of `REAL(KIND=8)` take 1616 kB (or 1579 KiB).

The stack size limit can be controlled by several mechanisms:

- On standard Unix system shells the amount of stack size is controlled by `ulimit -s <stacksize in KiB>`. This is also the stack size limit for the main OpenMP thread. The value of this limit is also used by the POSIX threads (`pthreads`) library as the default thread stack size when creating new threads.
- OpenMP supports control over the stack size limit of all *additional* threads via the environment variable `OMP_STACKSIZE`. Its value is a number with an optional suffix `k`/`K` for KiB, `m`/`M` ffor MiB, or `g`/`G` for GiB. This value *does not* affect the stack size of the main thread.
- The GNU OpenMP run-time (`libgomp`) recognises the non-standard environment variable `GOMP_STACKSIZE`. If set it overrides the value of `OMP_STACKSIZE`.
- The Intel OpenMP run-time recognises the non-standard environment variable `KMP_STACKSIZE`. If set it overrides the value of `OMP_STACKSIZE` and also overrides the value of `GOMP_STACKSIZE` if the compatibility OpenMP run-time is used (which is the default as currently the only available Intel OpenMP run-time library is the `compat` one).
- If none of the `*_STACKSIZE` variables are set, the default for Intel OpenMP run-time is `2m` on 32-bit architectures and `4m` on 64-bit ones.
- On Windows, the stack size of the main thread is part of the PE header and is embedded there by the linker. If using Microsoft's `LINK` to do the linking, the size is specified using the `/STACK:reserve[,commit]`. The `reserve` argument specifies the maximum stack size in bytes while the optional `commit` argument specifies the initial commit size. Both can be specified as hexadecimal values using the `0x` prefix. If re-linking the executable is not an option, the stack size could be modified by editing the PE header with [`EDITBIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd3shwhf.aspx). It takes the same stack-related argument as the linker. Programs compiled with MSVC's whole program optimisation enabled (`/GL`) cannot be edited.
- The GNU linker for Win32 targets supports setting the stack size via the `--stack` argument. To pass the option directly from GCC, the `-Wl,--stack,<size in bytes>` can be used.

Note that thread stacks are actually *allocated* with the size set by `*_STACKSIZE` (or to the default value), unlike the stack of the main thread, which starts small and then grows on demand up to the set limit. So don't set `*_STACKSIZE` to an arbitrary large value otherwise you may hit the process virtual memory size limit.

Here are some examples:

```
$ ifort -openmp my_module.f90 main.f90
```

Set the main stack size limit to 1 MiB (the additional OpenMP thread would get 4 MiB as per default):

```
$ ulimit -s 1024
$ ./a.out
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

Set the main stack size limit to 1700 KiB:

```
$ ulimit -s 1700
$ ./a.out
  0.000000000000000E+000
 (0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
  0.000000000000000E+000
 (0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
```

Set the main stack size limit to 2 MiB and the stack size of the additional thread to 1 MiB:

```
$ ulimit -s 2048
$ KMP_STACKSIZE=1m ./a.out
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  KMP_STACKSIZE=1m ./a.out
```

On most Unix systems the stack size limit of the main thread is set by PAM or other login mechanism (see `/etc/security/limits.conf`). The default on Scientific Linux 6.3 is 10 MiB.

Another possible scenario that can lead to an error is if the virtual address space limit is set too low. For example, if the virtual address space limit is 1 GiB and the thread stack size limit is set to 512 MiB, then the OpenMP run-time would try to allocate 512 MiB for each additional thread. With two threads one would have 1 GiB for the stacks only, and when the space for code, shared libraries, heap, etc. is added up, the virtual memory size would grow beyond 1 GiB and an error would occur:

Set the virtual address space limit to 1 GiB and run with two additional threads with 512 MiB stacks (I have commented out the call to `omp_set_num_threads()`):

```
$ ulimit -v 1048576
$ KMP_STACKSIZE=512m OMP_NUM_THREADS=3 ./a.out
OMP: Error #34: System unable to allocate necessary resources for OMP thread:
OMP: System error #11: Resource temporarily unavailable
OMP: Hint: Try decreasing the value of OMP_NUM_THREADS.
forrtl: error (76): Abort trap signal
... trace omitted ...
zsh: abort (core dumped)  OMP_NUM_THREADS=3 KMP_STACKSIZE=512m ./a.out
```

In this case the OpenMP run-time library would fail to create a new thread and would notify you before it aborts program termination.

Comment: I missed that, thought that these arrays are just 2 elements. Anyway I often use -fstack-arrays with arrays larger by orders of magnitude. But not with Ifort.

Comment: It's a bit confusing that with both `gfortran` and `ifort` the private copies of static arrays are always automatic and allocated on the thread stack despite any compiler options that might affect the placement of regular arrays.

Answer (score 12):

Segmentation fault is due to stack memory limit when using OpenMP. Using the solutions from the previous answer did not solve the problem for me on my Windows OS. Using memory allocation into heap rather than stack memory seems to work:

```
integer, parameter :: nmax = 202000  
real(dp), dimension(:), allocatable :: e_in
integer i

allocate(e_in(nmax))

e_in = 0

! rest of code

deallocate(e_in)
```

Plus this would not involve changing any default environment parameters.

Acknowledgement to and refer to ohm314's solution here: [large array using heap memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383326/fortran-openmp-large-array-on-eclipse-program-crash)

Comment: The main thread's stack size of Windows applications is specified at link time and cannot be freely controlled afterwards like on most Unix systems. My answer is Unix-specific. I will add a section about Windows. Of course, heap allocation is the best solution, except when one cannot really afford to make changes to the code.

Comment: Allocatable arrays are definitely the most robust option. No matter if Linux or Windows or whether using OpenMP or not when getting the stack overflow error.