# How to set openmp thread stack to unlimited?

Tags: fortran, openmp, intel-fortran, stack-size

Can someone tell me how to set OpenMP stack size to unlimited?
Like this link: [Why Segmentation fault is happening in this openmp code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264274/why-segmentation-fault-is-happening-in-this-openmp-code)

I also have a project  written by Fortran (customer‘s complex code), if I set `OMP_STACKSIZE`, the project is running normally. If I unset it, the project fails.

But, different input data have different `OMP_STACKSIZE`, so I must try it for each inputdata, (because I must save memory).

Can I set the OpenMP stack like pthread (`ulimit -s unlimited`)? Or have some way to set omp stack size dynamically?

I'm using RHEL 6.1, and the Intel compiler.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I remember seeing the ulimit -s trick somewhere in the intel fortran docs or FAQ before (which I cannot find again), so I believe this should work for you. I'm pretty sure this is an OS limitation, so it is the same regardless of your compiler, whether you have OpenMP or pthreads, or any other details like that.

Comment: You can't have unlimited stack sizes because you don't have unlimited memory. The operating system has to put your thread's stack somewhere. `ulimit -s unlimited` just means that the OS will permit you to use any stack size you wish.

Answer (score 5):

There is big difference between how the stacks of the main thread and of the worker threads are implemented.

The "unlimited" stack of the main thread starts at the highest virtual address available in user mode and grows downwards until it meets the program break (the end of the data segment) or hits another memory allocation (either named or anonymous mapping) at which point the program crashes.

Any additional stacks have to be placed somewhere in memory between the program break and the bottom of the main stack. They cannot have an arbitrary extendible length since their initial placements (i.e. the distance between their beginnings) determines their maximum sizes (and vice versa - the specified maximum sizes determine their initial placement). This is the reason why the Linux implementation of [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) (used by virtually all OpenMP runtimes in order to create new threads) states:

> On Linux/x86-32, the default stack size for a new thread is 2 megabytes.  Under the NPTL threading implementation, if the `RLIMIT_STACK` soft resource limit *at the time the program started* has any value other than "unlimited", then it determines the default stack size of new threads.  Using `pthread_attr_setstacksize(3)`, the stack size attribute can be explicitly set in the *attr* argument used to create a thread, in order to obtain a stack size other than the default.

In other words, the answer is no - you cannot specify unlimited stack size for threads other than the main one.