# Segmentation fault when enable $OMP DO loop

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am trying to modifying legacy code to initialize array with openmp. However, I encounter Segmentation fault when enabling $OMP DO derivatives in the following code sections. Would you please point out what might be wrong?

I am using fortran and compile with gfortran and variables are declared as common variables

```
   common/quant/keosc,vosc,rosc,frt,grt,dipole,v_solv
   common/quant_avg/frt_avg,grt_avg,d_coup,rv_avg,b_avg

    !$OMP PARALLEL 
!$OMP DO private(m,j,l,mp) firstprivate(nstates,natoms) lastprivate(rv_avg,b_avg,grt_avg,frt_avg,d_coup)
      do m = 0, nstates - 1 
         rv_avg(m) = 0d0
         b_avg(m) = 0d0
         do j = 1, 3
            grt_avg(m,j) = 0d0
            do l = 1, natoms
               frt_avg(m,l,j) = 0d0           
               do mp = 0, nstates - 1         
                  d_coup(m,mp,l,j) = 0d0         
               enddo                          
            enddo
         enddo
      enddo
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you measured where the CPU consumption is in your program?  It is a waste of effort to speed up portions that don't consume much CPU time.  I'd be surprised if array initializations were a high fraction of the CPU usage.  The code would be more readable if instead you used array notation, e.g., `rv_avg (0:nstates - 1) = 0d0`.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and comments. I am aware this will not be big performance boost.But wondering why I got error especially, anything wrong I did for common variables in openmp. Plus, for the information from https://www.xsede.org/tacc-stampede#tuning, the f90 array notation has some performance slowdown compared to the raw array notation

Comment: I'm sceptical of a performance slow down from using array notation for initialization.  Compilers are getting better and better.  Measure and find out...  Re the segmentation fault: it might be a stack size problem.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264274/why-segmentation-fault-is-happening-in-this-openmp-code

Comment: When using array notation, e.g. `rv_avg(:) = 0d0`, `gfortran` generates parallel code if the assignment statement is placed inside an OpenMP `PARALLEL WORKSHARE` construct. It doesn't work with vector assignments though, e.g. `rv_avg = 0d0` inside a workshare construct still results in the assginment being done in serial.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your declaration of the dimensions of any of the arrays so I speculate that the lines

```
do m = 0, nstates - 1 
     rv_avg(m) = 0d0
```

write to a non-existent element of `rv_avg`, that is the element at index `0`. Since Fortran programs don't, by default, check that array element accesses are within bounds, this write outside the bounds won't be caught by the run-time.  If the write stays within the address space of the program when it executes it won't cause a segmentation fault. Given the common block declarations the `0`-th element of `rv_avg` may well be part of `d_coup`.

Shake up the mapping of variables to address space by introducing OpenMP and it's easy to believe that the`0`-th element of `rv_avg` now lies outside the address space for a thread and causes the segmentation fault.

Since the program makes other references to array elements at `0` any one of them might be at the root of the segmentation fault.

Of course, if you follow @M.S.B.'s advice and use array syntax notation you can avoid out-of-bounds array accesses.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you do not have enough stack space in the OpenMP threads to hold the private copies of all these arrays. Especially `d_coup` looks like a really big one having `3 x natoms x nstates^2` elements. Most Fortran compilers nowadays automatically resort to using heap allocation for such big arrays but when it comes to `(first|last)private` variables, some OpenMP compilers, including GCC and Intel Fortran Compiler, always place them on the stack. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13266595/1374437) for more information.

**Edit:** Now I see that M. S. B. has actually linked to that same question in his comment.