# Segmentation fault when linking with Lapack and OpenMP

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, gfortran, lapack

When I link the following code

```
PROGRAM MAIN
implicit none
integer(8), PARAMETER :: N=2**9
complex(8) ::A(N,N),B(N,N),C(N,N)

C=matmul(A,B)
end program MAIN
```

with Lapack and OpenMP via:

> gfortran test.f95  -O3 -Wall -g  -std=f95 -cpp -I /usr/include/ -L
>   /usr/lib -lm  -fopenmp  -lpthread -lblas -llapack
>   -fexternal-blas

I get a segmentation fault. Reducing the dimension of the array to 2**8 or removing OpenMP removes the error. What is the reason for this?

Comment: What is your reason for `-I /usr/include/ -L /usr/lib -lm  -lpthread`? Why? Try to use as few flags as possible to be sure what causes it. This was enough for me : `gfortran statica.f90 -frecursive`. Ceterum censeo `integer(8)` or `kind=8` is very ugly code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `-fopenmp` implies `-frecursive` (try that one instead). That will cause the arrays to be placed on the stack and you get a stack overflow. By default the arrays will be static.

Tho compiler does this internally (`-fdump-tree-original`):

```
MAIN__ ()
{
  complex(kind=8) a[262144];
  complex(kind=8) b[262144];
  complex(kind=8) c[262144];
```

You could argue that it is not necessary to affect the main program arrays, because the main program is not re-entrant, but `-frecursive` does that. If you make th arrays `allocatable` they won't be affected.

Comment: So in order to compile my code with OpenMP, I have to use allocatable arrays, right?

Comment: Pretty much. You can also increase stack on the machine where it is run, but it may come again later.

Comment: I would have closed the question as duplicate of something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264274/why-segmentation-fault-is-happening-in-this-openmp-code , but I was surprised you have no OpenMP directive, I didn't realize `-frecursive` is sufficient before. I also don't like the emphasis on enlarging the stack there.  Maybe someone else will close it instead.