# OpenMP segmentation error with uncalled program subroutine

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran, subroutine

I have a very strange error when I enable OpenMP in my compilation options. I have pinned it down to a call to a module subroutine using a dynamic sized array from my main program subroutine. Here is a simplified example:

```
module arr_mod
contains
    subroutine add2_mod(arr)
        integer, dimension(:) :: arr
        integer i, n
        n = size(arr)
        do i=1,n
            arr(i) = arr(i)+2
        enddo
    end subroutine
end module

PROGRAM TEST_OMP
    use arr_mod
    integer, dimension(2000000) :: array
    array = 0
    write(*,*) array(1)
contains
    subroutine add2()
        ! Note that this subroutine is not even called in the main program...
        ! When the next line is commented, the program runs.
        call add2_mod(array)
    end subroutine
END PROGRAM TEST_OMP
```

When I compile and run this program without OpenMP, it runs fine:

```
$ gfortran -o test_omp test_omp.f90
$ ./test_omp
       0
```

But when I use OpenMP, the program immediately segfaults:

```
$ gfortran -o test_omp test_omp.f90 -fopenmp
$ ./test_omp
[1]    10291 segmentation fault  ./test_omp
```

If I remove the program subroutine (or simply comment the `add2_mod` call), it works fine even with OpenMP. It still works fine even if I call the `add2_mod` subroutine from the main program directly.

It also works when compiling with optimizations (tested with -O3), and when setting unlimited stack with `ulimit -s unlimited`.

As far as I can tell, it works fine with Intel Fortran (tested on version 17, with no specific flags other than -qopenmp).

Comment: What happens if you first do "ulimit -s unlimited"? What happens if you compile with optimisation? What version of gfortran? What version and what flags for Intel? Nice minimal example!

Comment: @IanBush I completed in the question. The program runs with either `-O3` (just tested `-O1` and it works too), or with `ulimit -s unlimited`. I used ifort 17 with the `-qopenmp` flag.

Comment: Just about to play chess so no time, but look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264274/why-segmentation-fault-is-happening-in-this-openmp-code?rq=1 and understand with the optimiser on the compiler can work out how to avoid the very large array. Inetl compiles by default with optimisation on, gfortran with it off.

Comment: @IanBush Intel will still works with `-O0`, but yes it could be some optimization difference.

Comment: @IanBush I am not sure it answers my question, since there is no OpenMP code in my question at all. I don't see how the stack size gets increased by simply including the openmp flag.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [gfortran documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/OpenMP.html):

> -fopenmp implies -frecursive, i.e., all local arrays will be allocated on the stack. When porting existing code to OpenMP, this may lead to
>   surprising results, especially to segmentation faults if the stacksize
>   is limited.

To overcome this limitation, you can force the array on the heap with the `allocatable` specifier:

```
module arr_mod
contains
    subroutine add2_mod(arr)
        integer, dimension(:) :: arr
        integer i, n
        n = size(arr)
        do i=1,n
            arr(i) = arr(i)+2
        enddo
    end subroutine
end module

PROGRAM TEST_OMP
    use arr_mod
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: array ! array is allocated on the heap
    allocate(array(2000000))
    array = 0
    write(*,*) array(1)
contains
    subroutine add2()
        call add2_mod(array)
    end subroutine
END PROGRAM TEST_OMP
```

Which will work fine with the `-fopenmp` flag.