# gfortran -fopenmp leads to Segmentation fault

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

I have the following code modified from https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-tutorial-c/top/multiplying-matrices-using-dgemm.html

```
! Fortran source code is found in dgemm_example.f

      PROGRAM   MAIN
      use omp_lib
      IMPLICIT NONE

      DOUBLE PRECISION ALPHA, BETA
      INTEGER          M, K, N, I, J
      integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
      PARAMETER        (M=2000, K=200, N=1000)
      DOUBLE PRECISION A(M,K), B(K,N), C(M,N), AT(K,M)

      PRINT *, "This example computes real matrix C=alpha*A*B+beta*C"
      PRINT *, "using Intel(R) MKL function dgemm, where A, B, and C"
      PRINT *, "are matrices and alpha and beta are double precision "
      PRINT *, "scalars"
      PRINT *, ""

      PRINT *, "Initializing data for matrix multiplication C=A*B for "
      PRINT 10, " matrix A(",M," x",K, ") and matrix B(", K," x", N, ")"
10    FORMAT(a,I5,a,I5,a,I5,a,I5,a)
      PRINT *, ""
      ALPHA = 1.0 
      BETA = 0.0

      PRINT *, "Intializing matrix data"
      PRINT *, ""
      DO I = 1, M
        DO J = 1, K
          A(I,J) = (I-1) * K + J
        !  AT(J,I) = (I-1) * K + J
        END DO
      END DO
      
      AT = TRANSPOSE(A)
      
      !write (*,*) A(1,2), AT(2,1)

      DO I = 1, K
        DO J = 1, N
          B(I,J) = -((I-1) * N + J)
        END DO
      END DO

      DO I = 1, M
        DO J = 1, N
          C(I,J) = 0.0
        END DO
      END DO

      PRINT *, "Computing matrix product using Intel(R) MKL DGEMM "
      PRINT *, "subroutine"
      !    C := alpha*op( A )*op( B ) + beta*C,
      !           M*K K*N              
      !CALL DGEMM('N','N',M,N,K,ALPHA,A,M,B,K,BETA,C,M)
      !             for op(A), op(B), LDA is for A
      CALL DGEMM('T','N',M,N,K,ALPHA,AT,K,B,K,BETA,C,M)
      
      
      
      PRINT *, "Computations completed."
      PRINT *, ""

      PRINT *, "Top left corner of matrix A:"
      PRINT 20, ((A(I,J), J = 1,MIN(K,6)), I = 1,MIN(M,6))
      PRINT *, ""

      PRINT *, "Top left corner of matrix B:"
      PRINT 20, ((B(I,J),J = 1,MIN(N,6)), I = 1,MIN(K,6))
      PRINT *, ""

 20   FORMAT(6(F12.0,1x))

      PRINT *, "Top left corner of matrix C:"
      PRINT 30, ((C(I,J), J = 1,MIN(N,6)), I = 1,MIN(M,6))
      PRINT *, ""

 30   FORMAT(6(ES12.4,1x))

      PRINT *, "Example completed."
      STOP 

      END
```

I tried to compile it by make

```
MKLROOT = /home/user/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.3.279/linux/mkl

CFLAGS = -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_scalapack_ilp64.a -Wl,--start-group -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_gf_ilp64.a -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_gnu_thread.a -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_blacs_openmpi_ilp64.a -Wl,--end-group -lgomp -lpthread -lm -ldl


#blas-1.exe: blas-1.f90
dgemm.exe: dgemm.f90
#   gfortran blas-1.f90 $(CFLAGS) -fopenmp -lblas -o blas-1.exe
    gfortran dgemm.f90  -lblas -fopenmp -o dgemm.exe
#   gfortran blas-1.f90  -lblas -fopenmp -o blas-1.exe
clean:
    rm *.exe
```

The compiling is OK. In running `./dgemm`,  it leads to  `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, when there is a `-fopenmp` flag in  `Makefile`.

I set `export OMP_STACKSIZE=6000m` in my `.bashrc` file

Why `-fopenmp` leads to this error message? Is that due to the example follows fortran 77 style, and has some issue with `-fopenmp`?

By using allocation, it solved my problem, as suggested in
[Why Segmentation fault is happening in this openmp code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264274/why-segmentation-fault-is-happening-in-this-openmp-code)
by ceeely

```
      real(dp), allocatable :: A(:,:), B(:,:), C(:,:), AT(:,:)
      
      if (.not. allocated(A))     allocate(A(M,K))
      if (.not. allocated(B))     allocate(B(K,N))
      if (.not. allocated(C))     allocate(C(M,N))
      if (.not. allocated(AT))     allocate(AT(K,M))
```

...

```
    deallocate(A,B,C,AT)
```

possibly heap is better than stack memory.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned it. I set ```export OMP_STACKSIZE=6000m``` in my ```.bashrc``` file, I think stacksize is not the problem.

Comment: I would still try making the arrays allocatable. As the OMP standard says at https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse54.html the behaviour is implementation defined if the requested size can not be provided which might be the case with 6Bbyte - with allocatable arrays you know for definite what you are getting

Comment: @AlphaF20 could you try `$ ulimit -s unlimited`?

Comment: Yup, looks like a duplicate. If I make the arrays allocatable or try ulimit -s it works. Otherwise I see the same as the question.

Comment: I shall try. But 6000m=6GB is quite large, I think.

Comment: Sorry, from where I use ```$ ulimit -s unlimited```?

Comment: @AlphaF20 That's the point - it's TOO large, more than the OS can provide. As such the implementation can ignore it and do whatever it wants. Hence allocatables are better

Comment: @jack, I tried ```ulimit -s unlimited in terminal```, it leads to  ```bash: ulimit: stack size: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument ``` :(  @Ian Bush, I have 16 GB memory with 64 bit OS, it should be affordable. I shall try ```allocate```. So far I have not solved my question from the link you mentioned :(

Comment: Last comment: It's has nothing to do with how much memory you have installed. It is what maximum stack size your OS allows.

Comment: OK, definitely my last comment: You may also want to look at https://craftofcoding.wordpress.com/2016/11/02/why-ulimit-is-not-a-cure-all-for-stack-problems/ which explains why ulimit doesn't solve your problems

Comment: Edited. Allocation works. Perhaps due to heap vs stack as ceeely's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264274/why-segmentation-fault-is-happening-in-this-openmp-code Thanks. Perhaps the question could be closed.