# OpenMP segmentation fault after parallel region with 1 thread

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, openmp

I am trying to parallelise a `do`-loop in Fortran 90 for the code that looks as follows:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(private) &
!$OMP& SHARED(cmesh, S) ! user-defined types with allocatable members. 
!$OMP DO
do i=1,cmesh%nelements

   Ke=0.d0
   ! skip details. Ke is populated inside another subroutine.

   do iii=1,(size(cmesh%Edof(1,:))-1) 
       do jjj=1,(size(cmesh%Edof(1,:))-1)
      
           ! add matrix Ke( real*8 (6,6) ) to elements of sparse matrix S:
           !$OMP CRITICAL
           call add( S, &
                     cmesh%dof_2_dof_free( cmesh%Edof( i, 1+iii ) ), &
                     cmesh%dof_2_dof_free( cmesh%Edof( i, 1+jjj ) ), &
                     Ke( iii, jjj ) )
           !$OMP END CRITICAL

       enddo
   enddo
enddo !i=1,cmesh%nelements
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
                    
call PARDISO( pt, 1, 1, 1, 13, cmesh%ndof_free, &
              S%a,  ! real*8, allocatable(43656)
              S%ia, ! integer*4, allocatable(1691)
              S%ja, ! integer*4, allocatable(43656)
              perm, 1, iparm, 0, &
              p_Rp, p_sol, error )
```

This works without OpenMP. If I enable OpenMP, the call to `PARDISO` throws the error:

```
Thread 1 stopped in mkl_pds_lp64_pardiso_c with signal SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault).

Reason/Origin: address not mapped to object (attempt to access invalid address).
```

even with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`. What am I doing wrong?

I compile with `ifort (IFORT) 19.0.5.281 20190815`.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. We need a real minimal reproducible example and the complete output.

Comment: According to the documentation at https://pardiso-project.org/manual/manual.pdf you are missing an argument in the call to paradiso, namely dparam that comes after error. This could cause the above problem, but without a complete example it is impossible to tell.

Comment: What's the declaration of `Ke`? Most Fortran compilers always put arrays declared `private` on the stack instead of placing the larger ones on the heap. This means the program will crash if the threads' stacks are too small. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13266595/1374437

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. @IanBush, I use Intel's MKL Pardiso, which does not have that last argument: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/sparse-solver-routines/onemkl-pardiso-parallel-direct-sparse-solver-interface/pardiso.html#pardiso . But your comment made me go through all of the arguments again and it says about `pt` that "The entries must be set to zero prior to the first call to pardiso.". Introducing this  fixes my problem. Oddly for me, it used to work without it without OpenMP.