# gfortran error ‘variable_1’ causes a section type conflict with ‘variable_2’

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, stack, openmp, gfortran

I'm trying to solve the possible problem of stack size being too small for an openmp fortran program with the compiler option `-mcmodel=medium` and error occurs while compiling:

```bash
Error: ‘profs’ causes a section type conflict with ‘sur’
/home/work/source_01.F:54:21:

   54 |      >   sur(nln), coll(nln), collat(nln),
      |                 ^
note: ‘sur’ was declared here
```

My code (part of source_01.F):

```fortran
      SUBROUTINE radr (jln,jlt,rntyear,rntday,scen,
     >   fixzero,nfrg,prnt)
      PARAMETER(nlt=32, nln=128, nlv=26, nbd=8)
      INTEGER nln, nlv, nbd, nlt
      REAL
     >   sur(nln), coll(nln), collat(nln), 
     >   profs(nln,nlv,nbd)
c
      SAVE sur, 
     >   profs
c    
        
C--------OpenMP--------------------------------------------------------
C$OMP THREADPRIVATE(sur, 
C$OMP>   profs)
C----------------------------------------------------------------------
      CALL rntradr (nlv,nln,nbd,abndc,
     >   sur,coll,collat,yrfrac,
     >   profs,scen,prnt)
      
      END
```

What could be causing the error in this case? Conflicting variables have different names, different dimensions, and are non-COMMON. Without the `-mcmodel=medium` flag, the program compiles fine, but crashes when I require more than one thread for the target openmp loop (it's far away in another file). My gcc version is 11.3.0 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1).

Comment: Where is this? In some subroutine? In a common block? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Oh dear, common and OpenMP, nor a happy mix. Decrementing and jumping if non-zero into the current millennium would be a good idea if at all possible.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава, thanks for comment! This code is part of the subroutine, not a `COMMON` block, and conflicting variables are not initialized below with a `DATA`, but their size is known at compile time. I'm not sure if I can reproduce my exotic bug with an artificial little example, but I'll try.

Comment: @IanBush, thanks you for participating, you're absolutely right, it's a _giant_ old code and I have to do everything I can without rewriting it all(

Comment: The crash can also be a typical stack overflow. I do not see a reason for the mcmodel flag. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264274/why-segmentation-fault-is-happening-in-this-openmp-code and many related Qs and As.